# Flattening a tuple in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am trying to turn a tuple of the form:

```
{{A,B,{C,A,{neg,A}}},{A,B,{neg,A}}}
```

Into

```
{{A,B,C,A,{neg,A}},{A,B,{neg,A}}
```

I'm quite new to Erlang so I would appreciate any hints. It makes no difference if the final structure is a list or a tuple, as long as any letter preceded by neg stays as a tuple/list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
convert({{A,B,{C,D,E}},F}) -> {{A,B,C,D,E},F}.
```

If why this works is puzzling, consider:

```
1> YourTuple = {{a, b, {c, a, {neg, a}}}, {a, b, {neg, a}}}.
{{a,b,{c,a,{neg,a}}},{a,b,{neg,a}}}
2> Convert = fun({{A,B,{C,D,E}},F}) -> {{A,B,C,D,E},F} end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.54118792>
3> Convert(YourTuple).
{{a,b,c,a,{neg,a}},{a,b,{neg,a}}}
```

The reason this happens is because we are *matching* over entire values based on the *shape* of the data. That's the whole point of matching, and also why its super useful in so many cases (and also why we want to use tuples in more specific circumstances in a language with matching VS a language where "everything is an iterable"). We can substitute the details with *anything* and they will be matched and returned accordingly:

```
4> MyTuple = {{"foo", bar, {<<"baz">>, balls, {ugh, "HURR!"}}}, {"Fee", "fi", "fo", "fum"}}.
{{"foo",bar,{<<"baz">>,balls,{ugh,"HURR!"}}},
 {"Fee","fi","fo","fum"}}
5> Convert(MyTuple).
{{"foo",bar,<<"baz">>,balls,{ugh,"HURR!"}},
 {"Fee","fi","fo","fum"}}
```

Why did this work when the last element of the top-level pair was so different in shape than the first one? Because *everything* about that second element was bound to the symbol `F` in the function represented by `Convert` (note that in the shell I named an anonymous function for convenience, this would be *exactly* the same as using `convert/1` that I wrote at the top of this answer). We don't *care* what that second element was -- in fact *we don't want to have to care* about the details of that. The freedom to selectively not care about the shape of a given element of data is one of the key abstractions we use in Erlang.

"But those were just atoms `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'` etc. I have different things in there!"

Just to make it look superficially like your example above (and reinforce what I was saying about not caring about exactly what we bound to a given variable):

```
6> A = 1.
1
7> B = 2.
2
8> C = 3.
3
9> AnotherTuple = {{A, B, {C, A, {neg, A}}}, {A, B, {neg, A}}}.
{{1,2,{3,1,{neg,1}}},{1,2,{neg,1}}}
10> Convert(AnotherTuple).
{{1,2,3,1,{neg,1}},{1,2,{neg,1}}}
```

Needing to do this is not usually optimal, though. Generally speaking the other parts of the program that are producing that data in the first place should be returning useful data types for you. If not you can certainly hide them behind a conversion function such as the one above (especially when you're dealing with APIs that are out of your control), but generally speaking the need for this is a code smell.

**And moving on**

The more general case of "needing to flatten a tuple" is a bit different.

Tuples are tuples because each location within it *has a meaning*. So you don't usually hear of people needing to "flatten a tuple" because that fundamentally changes the meaning of the data you are dealing with. If you have this problem, you should not be using tuples to begin with.

That said, we can convert a tuple to a list, and we can check the shape of a data element. With these two operations in hand we could write a procedure that moves through a tuplish structure, building a list out of whatever it finds inside as it goes. A naive implementation might look like this:

```
-module(tuplish).
-export([flatten/1]).

-spec flatten(list() | tuple()) -> list().
flatten(Thing) ->
    lists:flatten(flatten(Thing, [])).

flatten(Thing, A) when is_tuple(Thing) ->
    flatten(tuple_to_list(Thing), A);
flatten([], A) ->
    lists:reverse(A);
flatten([H | T], A) when is_tuple(H) ->
    flatten(T, [flatten(H) | A]);
flatten([H | T], A) when is_list(H) ->
    flatten(T, [flatten(H) | A]);
flatten([H | T], A) ->
    flatten(T, [H | A]).
```

Keep in mind that after several years of writing Erlang code I have *never* needed to actually do this. Remember: *tuples mean something different than lists*.

All that said, the problem you are facing is almost certainly handled better by using [records](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html).

Comment: I appreciate your answer @zxq9, and the reason for the silliness is that I had to use tuples when I was going through 5 steps of transforming a logical exp into CNF and I had to keep the integrity of a negated prop. That being said, I will take on board what you said since I am new to functional prog and erlang in particular. As for your answer, it does not take into consideration the main condition, that is to keep the negated tuple intact. You will also note that in my question I specified that the type of structure is of no difference to me, as long as it produces the clauses as specified

Comment: @PrOjEkTeD It *does* keep the negated tuple perfectly intact -- it matches over the entire thing, represented by the `E` variable in the matching clause of function `convert({{A,B,{C,D,E}},F})`. I'll add an example of why this happens in the answer.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain this, with Erlang being one of the worst documented languages I have came across, your explanation made things much clearer. Again, thank you.

Comment: @PrOjEkTeD I can sympathize with that :-) Erlang seems odd at first (coming from asm/C/Python). There is almost no introductory material to speak of (hence [LYSE](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/)), but once you got the basics down it is one of the most well documented languages around. Getting started was very much like finding materials to learn from when I was a kid in the '80s teaching myself. That's why I'm (slowly) working on an [intermediate instructional](http://zxq9.com/erlmud/) that focuses on architecture, style and the difference between "pure Erlang" and OTP.

Comment: @PrOjEkTeD By the way, when you run into a situation where you don't quite understand enough to ask a question there is a (very low-volume) chat room [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75358/erlang-otp). #erlang on Freenode and the [mailing list](http://www.erlang.org/static/doc/mailinglist.html) are both significantly more active than anything on SO and full of profoundly knowledgeable people (I also keep an #erlang room open on OFTC, but its *very* slow there).

Comment: I appreciate that @zxq9, once I have a good grip on the basics and know how to ask a question, I'll be there :)